# SSL connection requiring password in python 2.7

Tags: python, ssl

We want to establish an SSL connection with a service provider who requires a certificate AND a password. This seems easy to do on Curl (see below), because there is a SSLCERTPASSWD parameter (see below). But we would like to establish the connection with Python and its ssl library, where the only available argument is ca_cert (referring to the certificate file). Does anyone know a way to overcome this limitation on Python 2.7?

Here's the curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'asdf');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 5); // let server decide
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // this stops the data returning
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
if($result = curl_exec($ch) === false) {
  die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is using [pycurl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl) an option for you?

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, but it seems to be the best way forward. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If [pycurl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl) is an option. Something linke this might help you

```py
import pycurl
import StringIO

b = StringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
url = "https://example.com"
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, "/path/cacert.pem")
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEY, "/path/key_file.pem")
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, "/path/cert_file.pem")
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEYPASSWD, "your pass phrase")
c.perform()
c.close()
result = b.getvalue()
```